# Insert new calendar from SyncAdapter in Android

Tags: android, calendar

I'm facing some troubles with creating new calendar in Android. Here is my scenario:

I have app with account, also I have `SyncAdapter` which sync news etc., now I want to insert new calendar where I have new element to sync in Data and Synchronization where I can unchecked sync calendar (like in Google or Outlook account) and until I checked it again, I wouldn't see it in my calendar app.

Do you have any examples how to add Calendar in Data and Synchronization?

EDIT:

Ok, I know already how to add more options in Data and Synchronization menu, just define another provider `contentAuthority` in `your_syncadapter.xml` like:

`android:contentAuthority="com.android.calendar"`

But here I change `ContentProvider` for this `SyncAdapter`, what if I want to use different? Now i have `NullPointerException` because `ContentProvider` have nothing.

Comment: You want to save Data in your phone default calendar app?

Comment: No, I want to create my own calendar (not Calendar App!) connected with app account which I could see in every calendar app and I want  use `SyncAdapter` to do that.